# Kivy Audio Will Not Seek, Win 11

Tags: python, audio, kivy

According to the documentation Kivy 2.0.0 audio will likely not seek unless played first. However, I cannot get it to seek at all with this simple code on Windows 11. It always plays from the beginning and the position is always 0,

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.clock import Clock

sound = SoundLoader.load('test.mp3')

def play():
    sound.play()
    sound.seek(5)
    print(sound.get_pos())
    
if sound:
    print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
    print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
    #Clock.schedule_once(play, .3)
    
    play()
```

Also, I tried to schedule a delay using Clock and the audio does not play at all. What am I missing?

Edit:

It was suggested that this code needs to be wrapped in an app to work. That did fix the clock delay issue, but the player still will not seek ahead,

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MainApp(App):
    sound = SoundLoader.load('test.mp3')

    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Play', on_press = self.clock)

    def clock(self, evt):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.play, 1)
    
    def play(self, evt):
        self.sound.play()
        self.sound.seek(5)
        #self.sound.play()
        print(self.sound.get_pos())

MainApp().run()
```

Comment: I think you need an `App` running for these things to work.

Comment: @John: Thanks, wrapping the code in an app did solve the clock issue but not the seek problem. See edit in OP.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the Kivy source code I found out why Kivy audio will not seek.

The default Kivy audio provider on Windows is SDL2 and when I looked at the  source (kivy/core/audio/audio_sdl2.pyx) I found it does NOT have a seek method. Only "play" and "stop." In the **init**.py file the "seek" method returns "pass." However, the audio_ffpyplayer.py files DOES have a "seek" method. If one has ffpyplayer installed on his system Kivy will load it and seek will work, but with the default install it will not.

(It would be good if the Kivy Docs would reflect this. It would have saved me and others, I'm sure, a lot of "hair pulling.")

I tried ffpyplayer and it works good, but it has a lot of bloat. When packaged with pyinstaller there is around 40MB of added dlls. Since Windows already has the files needed to play audio, this bloat is redundant. While looking for a Python tool to play Windows audio using existing dlls, I found mp3play (https://github.com/michaelgundlach/mp3play). It is old but works flawlessly using only Window's native audio dlls and adds essentially no bloat. I think "playsound" will work as well.